# How to revert in git and delete all other pushes

Tags: git, github

me and my friends started working on a project connected with git. And there has come to some problems and we want to revert to a specific commit and delete all other pushes which crashed the project and we don't know how. We tried with

`git checkout <hash ID>`

but that only detaches the head and we can't publish this branch. What is the easiest way for us to do this? If there is a way just to revert and still keep the other pushes it would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

### **git reset** :

This option is bit risky as it alters your commit-history .
Also if you have some existing un-staged changes that you don't want to lose , you can use `--soft` instead of a `--hard` reset.

You can reset your branch to a specific commit with below command .

```
git reset --hard <commit-hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git reset` to go back to a previous commit.

The `git revert` command is where another commit would be made with the last commit being undone.

if you have already pushed to the remote repository, then a revert is better to use as others who may be working on the commit you are trying to remove.

More information in the following article,
https://opensource.com/article/18/6/git-reset-revert-rebase-commands